# How do I set a JavaScript object's value to null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this JS object from an array.

```
var rv = {};
$( ".part-name:visible" ).each(function( index ) {
   //rv[$(this).text()] = arrayPartsName[$(this).text()];
   rv[$(this).text()] = arrayPartsName[$(this).text()];
   console.log(rv);
})

4GN: "4GN"
4GNTS: "4GNTS"
042645-00: "042645-00"
503711-03: "503711-03"
573699-05: "573699-05"
```

I have to use this object with [Materialize Autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) and I have to edit it. The correct object must be, for example, like this

```
4GN: null
4GNTS: null
042645-00: null
503711-03: null
573699-05: null
```

How can do this?

Comment: can you post the html code ?

Comment: If you want your array keys to be null...why don't you just set them to null... `rv[$(this).text()] = null;`... I might be misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS the page HTML is generated using PHP. If you want I can post the full js code. Thank you.

Comment: @RohanBüchner thank you!

Comment: @LeonardoBarbiero you're welcome & welcome to StackOverflow. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up from my comment. You can just set it to `null` ;) JavaScript is quite a cool language... you can pretty much set any object's properties to anything you want, `null`, a specific value, or even a function... [see some more on the topic](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

But to focus on your specific question:

Change this line

```
rv[$(this).text()] = arrayPartsName[$(this).text()];
```

to

```
rv[$(this).text()] = null;
```

---

**Something to be aware of**

If you have `property` or key values in the JSON object with a dash in the name, you have to wrap it in quotes `"`, otherwise it wont be seen as valid. Although this might not be as evident, or an issue in your example as your keys are being added via the following function `$(this).text()`.

```js
var fruit = {
"pear": null,   // something null
"talk": function() { console.log('WOOHOO!'); }   // function
}

var apple = "app-le"; 

fruit[apple.toString()] = 'with a dash';
fruit["bana-na"] = 'with a dash';

// below is not allowed, the values will be evaluated as 
// properties that dont exist, and then your js will fail
// fruit[pe-ar] = 'with a dash';

fruit.talk();

console.log(fruit);
```